# How to solve two module imports each other in Django

Tags: django, django-orm

I have two models named as User and Newspaper. User can be author or reader and both are in the same model. So Newspaper has an author and it can create many newspapers. Reader has favorites and he can add as many newspapers as he want.

Question: How to solve circular import between two modules?

Extra info:
`user` and `newspaper` are two different apps.

```
├── project
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── db.sqlite3
├── manage.py
├── newspaper
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   └── views.py
└── user
    ├── admin.py
    ├── apps.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── migrations
    │   ├── 0001_initial.py
    │   └── __init__.py
    ├── models.py
    ├── tests.py
    └── views.py
```

newspaper/models.py

```
class NewsPaper(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=get_file_upload_path)
    author = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                            related_name="created_newspaper")

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title[:20] + '...' if len(self.title) > 20 else self.title
```

user/models.py

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True,
                                    validators=[validate_phone_number])
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    favorites = models.ManyToManyField(NewsPaper)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'phone_number'

    @property
    def my_uploaded_content(self):
        return self.created_newspaper.all()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.firstname} {self.lastname}'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ForeignKey without import this way:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    ...
    favorites = models.ManyToManyField('newspaper.NewsPaper')
    ...
```